# "Include" works weirdly

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I recently started development on Django 1.9 for python. I am a newbie in python as well. Just working through examples and codes to learn stuff.
I came across *include* in *django.conf.urls* which when I used caused errors. I couldn't understand why was that? Because I have used it at other places which don't cause errors.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from accounts import views as acc_views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home$', acc_views.home, name='accounts_home'),
]
```

Below is when this gives error.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home$', include(acc_views.home), name='accounts_home'),
]
```

Here is the exception:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x035424F8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35-32\VirtualENV\socialnetwork296\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 419, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35-32\VirtualENV\socialnetwork296\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35-32\VirtualENV\socialnetwork296\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python35-32\VirtualENV\socialnetwork296\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python35-32\VirtualENV\socialnetwork296\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python35-32\VirtualENV\socialnetwork296\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python35-32\VirtualENV\socialnetwork296\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 27, in check_resolver
    warnings.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
  File "C:\Python35-32\VirtualENV\socialnetwork296\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 27, in check_resolver
    warnings.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
  File "C:\Python35-32\VirtualENV\socialnetwork296\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python35-32\VirtualENV\socialnetwork296\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python35-32\VirtualENV\socialnetwork296\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 426, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<function home at 0x03D45A50>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

What is *include* actually doing?

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: Here is the Error, http://hastebin.com/akilovumow.tex

Comment: Please add the error to your question by editing  instead of linking an external site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`include` works by including other django module's urls and use current definition as root below other ones.

[Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) has very comprehensive explanation about this, I'm going to quote them here:

> ```
> from django.conf.urls import include, url
>
> from apps.main import views as main_views
> from credit import views as credit_views
>
> extra_patterns = [
>     url(r'^reports/$', credit_views.report),
>     url(r'^reports/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', credit_views.report),
>     url(r'^charge/$', credit_views.charge),
> ]
>
> urlpatterns = [
>     url(r'^$', main_views.homepage),
>     url(r'^help/', include('apps.help.urls')),
>     url(r'^credit/', include(extra_patterns)),
> ]
> ```

Here the `include(extra_patterns)` would use `credit/` as the root url and recognize any other urls defined in `extra_patterns` as an extension of the url definition to match urls. This avoids duplicate definitions like `credit/reports`, `credit/charge`, etc.

Same thing for `include('apps.help.urls')`, it would include all urls defined in module `apps.help.urls` with base url as `help/`. So you don't have to define all urls in one place.

Comment: thanks, this is quite thorough.      
`url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),`
 work without the *include* too. Why?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question, does it work without the `include`?

Comment: Do you mean removing that line totally and your admin still works?

Comment: `url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),` works like this.

Comment: Did you restart your django server after the change? I never used the admin url without `include`.

Comment: @RahulParashar - Admin is a special case since the `urls` is a property that constructs the urlpatterns in a different way. [urls property](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L264)

Comment: @ShangWang - Me neither till 5 mins ago :P

Comment: So, actually I pointed that out :-P.  Thanks for Explanation @Sayse

Comment: @RahulParashar - No worries, I'd never seen someone try to access them directly either so I got curious how django actually did it

Answer (score 5):

You appear to be including a `view` rather than a `urls` module

```
url(r'^home$', include(acc_views.home), name='accounts_home'),
```

should be

```
 url(r'^account/', include(account.urls, namespace='accounts'),
```

Include is designed to make it easy to link the patterns between different urls.py files, not to include a separate view, to do that you can just reference the view directly in a url as you would do normally.

> What is include actually doing?

You can view the [source code here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/urls/__init__.py#L19)

It essentially looks for patterns defined inside a `urlpatterns` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x035424F8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35-32\VirtualENV\socialnetwork296\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 419, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

That tells you everything you should need to know. A function is not iterable. If you [read the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.include) you'll see that you can use any of these:

```
include(module, namespace=None, app_name=None)[source]
include(pattern_list)
include((pattern_list, app_namespace), namespace=None)
include((pattern_list, app_namespace, instance_namespace))
```

You're passing it a function, I would guess, with `acc_views.home`. You probably want `'acc_views.home'` the *string* or something to that effect, not the actual module.